# Execute a script in post on both unstable and success in a jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My pipeline looks like that:

```
pipeline{
...
    post {
        always {
            archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'artifacts/**/*'
            script {
...
            }
            rtp stableText: '${FILE:artifacts/summary.html}', parserName: 'HTML'
        }
        success {
            script {
...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like that the script which is executed on success, was executed also on unstable, how can I achieve that?
Is there a way to specify `success or unstable {`?
Or is there a way to declare the action to take somewhere else and "invoke" it in a success and in an unstable tags?

Comment: [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post) It explains what are the post DSL can support. But If you want to run the fixed task with all scenario (success, failure, unstable) you can use `always {}`. I don't think there is a way to mention `success or unstable {}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can also do like below

```
def commonPostSteps() {
    echo "Hello World"
    script {
        def x =10
        print x + 20
    }
}
pipeline {
    agent any;
    stages {
        stage('one') {
            steps {
                echo "${env.STAGE_NAME}"
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            echo "post always"
        }
        success {
            commonPostSteps()
        }
        unstable {
            commonPostSteps()
        }
    }
}
```